# Can viral proteins cause infection?

Tags: microbiology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HIV Rapid Tests](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/hiv-rapid-tests)

Can proteins found on the surface of RNA viruses cause infection without the presence of the actual RNA and other components used in the virus?